# How to remove "Left Win"-key from "Input Source" - "Next source" binding

Tags: upgrade, shortcut-keys, 19.10

[image: Settings - Region Language - Input source options]

That binding seems to block all my other super key bindings like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> (go to workspace below) or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (switch keyboard layout)...

Background: During my 19.10 upgrade (from 19.04.) today, I got a config request in the terminal (ASCII UI) that asked me something like `choose key for 'latin switch'`. I didn't know what to do and, smart as I am, selected 'left logo' as the key; I guess that's were I messed up...

Edit:

What I tried:

- remove from *settings* -> *devices* -> *keyboard shortcuts* but `left win is not listed there`
- remove `grp:lwin_toggle` from file `/etc/default/keyboard`, line `XKBOPTIONS="grp:lwin_toggle,grp_led:scroll"` but no effect...

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I (of course AFTER posting the above question) figured it out:

Use "Gnome Tweak Tool".

Go to

- "Keyboard & Mouse"
- "Additional Layout Options"
- "Switching to another Layout"
- Uncheck "Left Win"

(for the unlikely case someone else got this very problem)